# X-axis label on two rows

Tags: matlab, plot, label, matlab-figure

```
str = {'HS31'; 'HS31 (Ridotto)';
    'Dax85';'Dax85 (Ridotto)';
    'FTSE89';'FTSE89 (Ridotto)';
    'SP98';'SP98 (Ridotto)';
    'Nikkei22';'Nikkei225 (Ridotto)';
    'SP457';'SP457 (Ridotto)';
    'Russ1318';'Russ1318 (Ridotto)';
    'Russ2151';'Russ2151 (Ridotto)';
    'Eurostoxx';'Eurostoxx (Ridotto)';
    'Ftse';'HS31 (Ridotto)';
    'Mibtel';'Mibtel (Ridotto)';
    'SP';'SP (Ridotto)';
    'Nasdaq';'Nasdaq (Ridotto)';

};
h=figure;
bar(t);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',str, 'XTick',1:numel(str))

saveas(h, 'Backtesting/computing_time.png');
```

I can't read the text below the plot. Do you know how to fix it?

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g43iegh4oeng3kf/computing_time.png
[image]

Comment: You could maybe [rotate the labels](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27812-rotate-x-axis-tick-labels) or use a custom made solution based on `text` (roughly similar to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888482/matlab-two-levels-of-y-axis-tick-labels-in-text-on-imagesc)). If I have some time later and nobody did it before I will write a full example.

Comment: here's another alternative solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886679/is-there-a-way-to-plot-axis-values-with-different-alternating-heights/17887654#17887654

Comment: You also have in every second label the text of the label before included. It might not be necessary.I nicer layout would maybe just print 1:2:end labels and color the bars named (Ridotto) in another color.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are okay with 90 degrees rotated text, you may try this code that is based on a very useful x-label rotating text tool, available [`here`](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabel-rotate)

**Code**

```
h=figure;
bar(randi(9,26,1),'EdgeColor','g') %// Assumed random data for demo
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',str, 'XTick',1:numel(str))
xticklabel_rotate([],90,str);%% File-exchange code %// xlabel text rotated
saveas(h, 'computing_time.png');
```

**Sample plot with some random data**

[image]

If you are okay with down-sampling the x-label text, i.e. for example show only every other
label, use this right before creating the figure handle -

```
str(1:2:end)={[]}
```

Rest of the code stays the same. The output plot would look like this -

[image]

If you still want to keep the data horizontal, you need to downsample the number of labels by a good factor. In your given sample case, a factor of `4` worked. The changes in the code is adding the following code right after declaring `str` and of course commenting the x-label rotating tool usage -

```
str1 = cell(1,numel(str));
str1(1:4:end) = str(1:4:end);
str = str1;
```

The trick here is to use empty cells for the x-labels that you want to skip.

Result -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whats missing in the answer by Divakar is actually a solution with two (or more) rows. You can simulate it with text boxes at certain positions.

```
str = {'HS31'; 'HS31 (Ridotto)';
    'Dax85';'Dax85 (Ridotto)';
    'FTSE89';'FTSE89 (Ridotto)';
    'SP98';'SP98 (Ridotto)';
    'Nikkei22';'Nikkei225 (Ridotto)';
    'SP457';'SP457 (Ridotto)';
    'Russ1318';'Russ1318 (Ridotto)';
    'Russ2151';'Russ2151 (Ridotto)';
    'Eurostoxx';'Eurostoxx (Ridotto)';
    'Ftse';'HS31 (Ridotto)';
    'Mibtel';'Mibtel (Ridotto)';
    'SP';'SP (Ridotto)';
    'Nasdaq';'Nasdaq (Ridotto)';};
bar(rand(26, 1));
% clear labels existing so far
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', {});

% parameters
spacing = 0.03; % between different rows of labels and between x-axis and label
rows = 2; % number of rows in staggered layout
heightAdjust = 0.1; % reduce height of figure to make space for vertically stacked labels

pos = get(gca,'Position');
set(gca, 'Position', pos+ [0 heightAdjust 0 -heightAdjust] )

ylim = get(gca, 'YLim');
for i = 1 : length(str) % for all labels
    % compute y position of label (depends on x, therefore staggered)
    y = ylim(1) - spacing - spacing * mod(i - 1, rows);
    % print text box at correct position to simulate label
    text('Units', 'Data', 'Position', [i, y], 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', 'String', str(i));
end
```

The number of rows and some spacing parameters have to be set manually. And it looks like this when the figure is maximized.

[image: Matlab figure with labels in rows]

Comment: However I actually would prefer the 90 degree rotated solutions because the label text is still very long and two rows might not be enough.

Comment: yeah I guess we need to look at such problems on a case by case basis.  Good solution by you and might be the one actually asked by OP! Having different options won't hurt I think and for the given data, rotated ones would look better in my opinion too. +1

Answer (score 0):

You could just type the control character `\newline` inside the label.