# Count the frequency of each character in a large text file using matlab

Tags: matlab, probability

I am trying to read a huge text file and count the frequency of each letter then I want to find the probability distribution of each letter.
this is what I am trying so far:

```
f = fopen('c:\words.txt');
ns = textscan(f, '%s');
fclose(f);

counts = hist(num, 1:26); 
prob = counts / numel(ns{:})
```

any hints, help, working code?

I was trying this code also but the answer is not accurate

```
fid = fopen('c:\words.txt');
c = fread(fid);
fclose(fid);


y = unique(c);
counts = histc(c, y);
```

I would like to get result like:

```
a = 2338 times
b = 4533 times 
c = 1233 times
```

etc...

regards,

Comment: How huge? You mean so huge that you need to read it in small chunks?

Comment: have you tried this? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7738-countmember

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For huge text files, you might want to avoid `hist` or `histc`.

**Code**

```
%// Convert everything to chars
letters_char = reshape(char(ns{:}),[],1);

%// Get the case-insensitive count of each letter 
count_lettters = sum(bsxfun(@eq,letters_char,97:122),1) + ...
    sum(bsxfun(@eq,letters_char,65:90),1)
```

Finally, to get the probability distribution, use `plot(count_lettters./sum(count_lettters))` or `bar(count_lettters./sum(count_lettters))`, whichever looks nicer to you.

Then, if you would like to add labels to probabilities of each of those letters, use `set(gca, 'XTickLabel',cellstr(char(97:122)'),'XTick',1:26)`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746964/x-axis-label-on-two-rows)

Sample plot -

[image]

*Now, this was a random text file and it shows at least one interesting fact that `'e'` might be the most frequently occurring letter in a typical text.*

Comment: how I can calculate the probability distribution for the result and plot it in graph?

Comment: @user2085339 You mean something like this - `plot(count_lettters./sum(count_lettters))` or `bar(count_lettters./sum(count_lettters))`?

Comment: last help please.... I want to replace the number of char (1-26) with letters from (a-z) in x axis

Comment: it is perfect ***** support

Answer (score 0):

This can read all characters at waonce into array A

```
fileID = fopen('words.txt','r');
A = fscanf(fileID, '%c');   % this also works for unicode characters.
fclose(fileID);
```

Using Map, you can count the occurrence of all characters:

```
for i = 1:numel(A)

    if isKey(keyMap, A(i))
        keyMap(A(i)) = keyMap(A(i)) + 1;
    else
        keyMap(A(i)) = 1;
    end        
end
```