# Matlab: Bar chart x-axis labels missing

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I'm using the following code to create a bar chart in matlab.

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
bar(a)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine'})
```

Code works fine except that x-axis labels don't appear on their corresponding position on the x-axis. How do I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: What is their corresponding position? The labels seem to sit on the tick marks to me...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746964/x-axis-label-on-two-rows/23747408#23747408) might be inspiring enough for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set `XTickLabel`, you are telling Matlab to replace the text where each tick *currently* is with new text that you provide. If you run only the first two lines, you will see that Matlab by default has put XTicks on 0:2:20. You can resolve the issue by first telling Matlab to put ticks for each individual bar, and then re-labeling these ticks:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
bar(a)
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:length(a))
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine'})
```

You will have a pretty cluttered x-axis at this point...you would want to look into rotating the XTickLabels with the [rotateXLabels](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27812-rotatexlabels--ax--angle--varargin--) function from FileExchange or with the built-in functionality on Matlab14b and later.